# Azure ADO CICD Pipeline for pytest while resolving Airflow variables

Tags: python-2.7, pytest, airflow-2.x

**Background**

pytest test_create_fivetran_job.py is erroring out while running it in the Azure ADO CICD pipeline.

This script tests the create_fivetran_job.py

**Funcationality**: create_fivetran_job.py reads the configuration settings from Snowflake config table and creates a refresh job in Fivetran using the API calls. This script is scheduled via Airflow MWAA DAG. The details required for the execution like: Auth_URL, fivetran login credentials, snowflake credentials are set up as variables in Airflow.

The python and DAG's are running successfully however pytest pipeline is failing.

How can I run the pytest pipeline by resolving the variables ?

I have verified the Airflow variables, contents of yml files. The script [create_fivetran_job.py] is being triggered successfully by the DAG's.

However the pytest isn't resolving the variables.

```
    Error: 
    ______________ ERROR collecting tests/test_create_fivetran_job.py ______________
    tests/test_create_fivetran_job.py:43: in <module>
        from ..dags.scripts import create_fivetran_job
    dags/scripts/create_fivetran_job.py:19: in <module>
        AUTH_URL = Variable.get("fivetran_auth_url")
    /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.7.17/x64/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/variable.py:140: in get
        raise KeyError(f'Variable {key} does not exist')
    E   KeyError: 'Variable fivetran_auth_url does not exist'
```

------------------------------- Captured stdout --------------------------------
[2024-02-05 20:01:09,116] {variable.py:274} ERROR - Unable to retrieve variable from secrets backend (MetastoreBackend). Checking subsequent secrets backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.7.17/x64/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1911, in _execute_context
cursor, statement, parameters, context
File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.7.17/x64/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 736, in do_execute
cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: variable

```
    The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.7.17/x64/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/models/variable.py", line 267, in get_variable_from_secrets
        var_val = secrets_backend.get_variable(key=key)
      File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.7.17/x64/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/session.py", line 70, in wrapper
        return func(*args, session=session, **kwargs)
      File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.7.17/x64/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/secrets/metastore.py", line 64, in get_variable
        var_value = session.query(Variable).filter(Variable.key == key).first()
      File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.7.17/x64/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2824, in first
        return self.limit(1)._iter().first()
      File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.7.17/x64/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2919, in _iter
        execution_options={"_sa_orm_load_options": self.load_options},
      File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.7.17/x64/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1717, in execute
        result = conn._execute_20(statement, params or {}, execution_options)
      File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.7.17/x64/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1710, in _execute_20
        return meth(self, args_10style, kwargs_10style, execution_options)
      File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.7.17/x64/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 335, in _execute_on_connection
        self, multiparams, params, execution_options
      File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.7.17/x64/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1587, in _execute_clauseelement
        cache_hit=cache_hit,
      File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.7.17/x64/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1954, in _execute_context
        e, statement, parameters, cursor, context
      File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.7.17/x64/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2135, in _handle_dbapi_exception
        sqlalchemy_exception, with_traceback=exc_info[2], from_=e
      File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.7.17/x64/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 211, in raise_
        raise exception
      File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.7.17/x64/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1911, in _execute_context
        cursor, statement, parameters, context
      File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.7.17/x64/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 736, in do_execute
        cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
    sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: variable
    [SQL: SELECT variable.val AS variable_val, variable.id AS variable_id, variable."key" AS variable_key, variable.description AS variable_description, variable.is_encrypted AS variable_is_encrypted 
    FROM variable 
    WHERE variable."key" = ?
     LIMIT ? OFFSET ?]
    [parameters: ('fivetran_auth_url', 1, 0)]
    (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)
```